# Make Calculation in Model Class

Tags: asp.net-core, model

I want to do some calculation in the Model class because I am using certain search input to return the whole result as a list. Therefore, it is not possible to change the grid view result.

```
public class TaxInvoiceEnquiryModel : ModelStatus
{
    [DisplayField(Width = 200, TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Left, Text = "Tax Charges")]
    [ValidProperty]
    public double TaxCharges { get; set; }

    [DisplayField(Width = 200, TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Left, Text = "Sales Charges")]
    [ValidProperty]
    public double SalesCharges { get; set; }

    [DisplayField(Width = 200, TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Left, Text = "Total Charges")]
    [ValidProperty]
    public double TotalCharges { get; set; }

}
```

From the list, I only can retrieve the TaxCharges and TotalCharges. As told, I need to calculate the SalesCharges by TotalCharges deduct TaxCharges and display it UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you need:

```
public class TaxInvoiceEnquiryModel : ModelStatus
{
    [DisplayField(Width = 200, TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Left, Text = "Tax Charges")]
    [ValidProperty]
    public double TaxCharges { get; set; }

    [DisplayField(Width = 200, TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Left, Text = "Sales Charges")]
    [ValidProperty]
    public double SalesCharges
    {
        get
        {
            return TotalCharges - TaxCharges;
        }
    }

    [DisplayField(Width = 200, TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Left, Text = "Total Charges")]
    [ValidProperty]
    public double TotalCharges { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Yes, this is what exactly what I want, but may I know the Return keyword will be the same uses as SET?

Comment: Glad to assist. No, the return keyword is for returning the result of TotalCharges - TaxCharges in the getter of the SalesCharges property. SalesCharges is a read-only property because it depends on the other two properties so you should not be able to set it without also changing the value of the other properties.